# Every time I boot my pc a website loads

Tags: windows-registry, popups, virus-removal, malware-removal

the website is http://gameloft.name/ obviously a malware

but I did run programs like rkill (http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/rkill/)

Then adwcleaner then spybot then browserbased scanners like the eset one or cloudbased like the norton one.. run my native antivirus which is bitdefender 2016 fully update checked registry with tuneup/bitdefender/ccleaner cleaned everything

did the same procedure on safemode as well

did use bitdefenders rescue mode that reboots to a linux environment on which I updated the antivirus and rescanned everything

I used those kasperskytools to scan for specific rootkits worms etc nothing...

every time I reboot I get this webpage popped up just once (after I close it it doesnt reappear until I reboot again)  and I dont know what to do :/

Edit I did all that in the post you link to me .... first read the main post not just the title before rushing into conclusions... I also forgot to mention that I run msconfig as well and killed anything non microsoft product (or nvidia or bitdefender) fom my startup list... I also run process explorer and autoruns both linked to totalvirus and nothing showed up as a virus...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: how so ?  I just described that I did all that and still have no result...

Comment: Is it possible to screenshot website (safety of others)

Comment: What ever was found during those scans was obviously removed I thought that would be self explanatory... also rkill  is a tool that makes malware trackable again not to mentio that I run scans while on linux and on safemode so malware should be detectable under those circumstances its obviously a new sort of malware or a different problem (a specific reg key or whatever)

Comment: @Racing121 the website it self is safe -if you use adblocker and bluhell firewall blugin like me that is and dont click on any links inside it... -  its something in russian and has some adult explicit stuff use this online crossbrowser to load it there if you like to be even more safe https://www.browserling.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try Sysinternals Autoruns to find the automatically launching URL. Download the program at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx and look through the various startup programs (there are a lot). I think you can also search for the offending link.